# Are people improperly using the collectingAndThen method for Streams/Collectors?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've been seeing a lot of `Stream` examples that use the `Collectors` `collectingAndThen` method in the terminal `collect` operation. In a lot of these examples, the `finisher` argument (for the 2nd parameter of the `collectingAndThen` method) is a relatively simple call that shouldn't require the `collectingAndThen` method because the resulting data structure from just using the first `Collector` can be passed as an argument to the method in the `finisher` parameter, and in-fact calling `collectingAndThen` adds unnecessary operations.

For example (using the actual example in the [Oracle documentation for `collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-), I know this is an extremely overly simple example but I've seen a lot of people on StackOverflow and other sites doing similar things with just 1 or 2 intermediary operations and its simplicity isn't the factor in question here)-

```
List<String> people =
     people.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
```

Accomplishes the same as-

```
List<String> people = Collections.unmodifiableList(
     people.stream().collect(toList());
```

But using `collectingAndThen` in the first example is adding unnecessary operations (you can look at the [OpenJDK implementation of `Collectors`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java) to see its source code).

I understand there are necessary times to use the method, and sometimes it is cleaner. But is it being improperly used in cases that are like this or am I missing something?

Comment: Where is the 'unnecessary operations' ! Both examples are working the same way; the first one collect data into list then create an unmodifiableList from the stream result, the second do exactly the same things. `collectingAndThen` operation is just a suite of final operations that make things works in a stream (pipeline) fashion way, you can achieve the same result using other methods

Comment: Related: [Is collectingAndThen method enough efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47810524/1371329) The comment from Brian Goetz seems relevant here.